# Customize the size of a text field in Rails with twitter-bootstrap-rails gem

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In Rails 5, I have a text input field which is styled using Bootstrap with the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem.

```
<div class='container'>
  </div class='form-control'>
  <%= form_tag pages_home_path, remote:true, id: 'submit-text-button' do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :text, params[:text], :required => 'required', class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Submit your text', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block' %></div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Normally I would have done some thing like:

```
<textarea class='form-control' cols="186" rows="10" required="required" name="text"></textarea>
```

but I'm not sure how this translates to Rails. I tried different solutions but nothing worked. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Replace `text_field_tag` with `text_area`. I think you are looking for [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_area)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

```
<div class='container'>
  </div class='form-control'>
  <%= form_tag pages_home_path, remote:true, id: 'submit-text-button' do %>
    <%= text_area_tag :text, params[:text], :required => 'required', class: 'form-control', :rows => 10 %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Submit your text', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block' %></div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and you can also add `size`

```
<%= text_area_tag :text, params[:text], :required => 'required', class: 'form-control', :size =>"25x10" %>
```

here `cols=25` and `rows=10`

Hope this will work for you. Thanks!